# How to format a particular value in array of object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hi I am getting some data from api and one particular value need to be in proper way. Can you please provide some kind of solution for this ?

```
const data = [ 
{ state: 'Test-1.5', response: "ABC" },
{ state: 'Test-2.5', response: "XYZ" },
{ state: 'Test', response: "GHD" },
];
```

Below should be expected data after format, need to remove the number from state which start from (-) if it is exist

```
const expectedData = [ 
{ state: 'Test', response: "ABC" },
{ state: 'Test', response: "XYZ" },
{ state: 'Test', response: "GHD" },
];
```

Comment: What have you tried and what didn’t work as expected?

Comment: Consider using the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try mapping the array, splitting the text in "-" and get what comes before it, like this:

```js
const data = [ 
{ state: 'Test-1.5', response: "ABC" },
{ state: 'Test-2.5', response: "XYZ" },
{ state: 'Test', response: "GHD" },
];

const formatted = data.map(data => ({...data, state: data.state.split("-")[0]}))

console.log(formatted)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [ 
{ state: 'Test-1.5', response: "ABC" },
{ state: 'Test-2.5', response: "XYZ" },
{ state: 'Test', response: "GHD" },
];

// pure 
const result = data.map(({state, ...props}) => ({state: state.replace(/-[\d.]+$/, ''), ...props}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));

// mutable
data.forEach(item => item.state = item.state.replace(/-[\d.]+$/, ''));
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```